# Famous black mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Are there any famous black mathematicians?

By famous, I mean in the sense of having a theorem or well-known result named after them.

Comment: Try [here](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/mad/madgreatest.html) or start from [there](http://www.math.buffalo.edu/mad/). There is also [this](http://www.math.upenn.edu/History/bh/text99.html), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_African-American_mathematicians), and you could at least have tried [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=black+mathematician).

Comment: I am afraid to say no, there are none. An those listed in the links certainly aren't famous

Comment: Unsurprisingly there are no very-very well known black mathematicians, and for that matter almost no very well known black scientists: those people were enslaved, murdered, brutalized, humilliated, put down, seggregated, bothered...for long centuries. Let's not forget that even in the USA, until only some 50 years ago, were lots of places (good'ol south...ah!) with restaurants, buses, schools, etc. only for whites or for blacks, and even now they haven't achieved equality of conditions and opportunities. Perhaps in some centuries more...if we can live without bothering others for their skin.

Comment: [David Blackwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Blackwell) *is* famous, and reading [ths](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/cifamerica/2012/apr/12/black-mathematicians-john-derbyshire-fields-medal) is also very interesting.

Comment: @000: I find your remark a little bit ignorant (in the literal, not offensive, sense of the word). While "fame" is a rather relative and slippery term, [David Blackwell](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Blackwell) certainly fits the bill, in my mind. Fundamental contributions in probability, stochastic processes and statistics, with his name attached to among the most famous theorems in mathematical statistics and renewal theory. He also "dabbled" in game theory.

Comment: @cardinal: in YOUR opinion, but basically you have to be interested in his fields of math to know him, whereas hilbert, grothendieck, serre, mac lane are known to anyone having at least some mathematics education

Comment: I'd say that Al-Kashi was hugely important. But I can't think of somebody else. : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamsh%C4%ABd_al-K%C4%81sh%C4%AB

Comment: _(The comment thread seems to have devolved into an off-topic discussion better suited for chat. As such many comments have been purged.)_

Comment: My homework is write about the life of ten "famous" black mathematicians and your researchs... I guess that will be hard, or impossible.

Comment: You may be interested in the interview with David Blackwell, in Donald J. Albers, and Gerald L. Alexanderson, **Mathematical People: Profiles and Interviews** (2 ed.), A K Peters. The interview touches on the question of race in mathematics.

Comment: [Nira Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nira_Chamberlain) is the president of the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications in the UK.

Answer (score 11):

[David Blackwell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Blackwell) is one of the creators of the Rao-Blackwell Theorem.

Comment: (+1) ...and *Blackwell's Theorem*, one of the fundamental contributions to renewal theory which extends the elementary renewal theorem. Among (many) other contributions...

Answer (score 6):

Banyaga's theorem on the group of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms of a closed surface was mentioned [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2458739).  Banyaga is a black mathematician. Banyaga's article proving this is very influential by mathematical standards: it is cited over 80 times at MathSciNet.

Comment: 80 times? I think you have your very own standards of what it means to be famous

Comment: @000, I am merely comparing Banyaga to other mathematicians as far as MathSciNet citation rates are concerned. Having an article with 80 citations is usually an indication of strong notability. Consider, for example, the fact that [Shmuel Weinberger's](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/mrcit/individual.html?mrauthid=181430) most cited work has 51 citations.

Comment: I was just asking as all of my professors have a multiple of his citations